# Android Listview with multiple views

Tags: android, listview

I am working on a Android project having a list view where every row shows up like a card. Hence I created separate views for each of its row.

**How do I handle these multiple views in adapter Class?**

Is there any code design pattern that help separately handling these views?

Thank in advance

Comment: do all items gonna look same with different values on card..?

Answer (score 0):

you should use `typeCount` inside your adapter. here is [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getViewTypeCount%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

Your adapter needs to implement `getItemViewType()` and `getViewTypeCount()` methods to let listview handle different types of layouts per row properly. See docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html

Answer (score 0):

I would use a recycler view. A good example of one is [here](http://pixio.com/blog/2016-06-10/reduce-reuse-recyclerview/)